# How to pass arguments from a message to a telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

my telegram bot receives messages in one line of the following form: 323 432 875-1

How can I send this string to three variables using telebot ?

```
idr = 323
numb = 432 
prid = 875-1
```

UPD#

```
text = "323 432 875-1"
idr, numb, prid, *_ = l = text.split()
```

This works, but I can't figure out how to get the data from Telegram itself and transfer it to the text = ""

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `text = "323 432 875-1"`
                                    `idr, numb, prid, *_ = l = text.split()`

This works, but I can't figure out how to get the data from Telegram itself and transfer it to the text = ""

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a message, the text is saved in `message.text`.

So:

```
text = message.text
idr, numb, prid, *_ = l = text.split()
```